# How to freely move the table in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: windows, libreoffice

What I'm trying to do here is cook up some tables in Writer, then convert the .doc to a .pdf. However, I'm trying to design a box with tables so I need to be able to move them to the middle and not just align to the left, etc.

How would I go about doing that?  What I've tried to do is put the tables together in Writer, then just print screen and paste into Paint and put it together there, but the resulting .pdf looks really bad (all pixelated).

Basically what I want to do is this:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/KTb7N]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LibreOffice Draw or Impress.  In either case, go to `Insert -> Table`.

In Draw and Impress, it is possible to move tables by clicking and dragging, unlike in Writer.

**EDIT**:

It is possible to create a plain table by making a few changes to the settings.  Select the table and make sure the table toolbar is showing at the bottom: `View -> Toolbars -> Table`.

Then change the border color to black, and change the fill color to none.
[image]

Also, uncheck `Banded rows` in the sidebar.

[image]

Now the table should be plain with black borders, although it will still appear blue when selected.

Since this requires several settings, it may be fastest to copy and paste the table whenever an additional table is needed.

Comment: @fixer1234: In Draw and Impress, it is possible to move tables by clicking and dragging, unlike in Writer.  The quality issue will also be resolved because Paint will not be needed.  So I believe my answer solves the question fully.  If there is any confusion then I can explain in more detail.

Comment: not sure why i didn't think of this hehe. i'll fool around with Draw. something that's been bothering me, is there a way to get rid of the table design? i just want black borders, none of this fancy coloring

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: that did the trick, i feel like such a noob now. why isn't it like that by default!

thanks!